# Are online subversion systems secure?

Tags: legal, unfuddle.com

I am using [private free unfuddle package](http://unfuddle.com/accounts/plans). I commit my personal code there. I want to know whether my code is secure and if it is only *my* property? Or does unfuddle have rights to use or share my code?

I read their [privacy policy](http://unfuddle.com/support/privacy_policy) but I am little bit confused. Can someone explain it to me  in simple words?

I want to keep my code as only my property but also want to get benefits of subversion technology.

Comment: Vote to move to legal.stackexchange.com =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [Terms of Service](http://unfuddle.com/support/terms_of_service):

> If you create a project on the Website, then you are the owner of that account and all Content stored therein. Unfuddle.com and Unfuddle will not disclose any of your Content unless required to do so by court order or other legal action.

It is clearly your property, and they would not have any rights to use your code. They can only share your code if a court orders them to.

So, in summary, check the **terms of service** when looking at websites, not just the privacy policy. :)

Comment: Jeff Atwood: I did not think about **Terms of Service** page before. It is clear now. Thanks.